# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int, int[])

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

This is my code:

```
int[] myCards = takeMyCardsFromDB(); // returns an int[]
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.row_my_roster_card, myCards);
```

I don't have many experience with  the ArrayAdapter. I see that these are the public constructors for ArrayAdapter:

- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)`
- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)`
- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`
- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`
- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)`
- `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`

What is wrong in my constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because an `int[]` is *not* an `Integer[]`.

Autoboxing only works with singular types, not with arrays: `int` can be autoboxed to `Integer`, but `int[]` cannot be autoboxed to `Integer[]`.

You need to convert the `myCards` to an `Integer[]`. The following method can do the job:

```
public static Integer[] autoboxArray(int[] array) {
    Integer[] newArray = new Integer[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: thanks. probably the late hour sent me out of my head